# Android studio button fixed color can't be changed

Tags: java, android, button, background-color

can someone help me
I'm using a button in android ,I'm unable to change the button color , this is my xml code :

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="584dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the attribute `android:backgroundTint`. For example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    <!-- ADD THE LINE BELOW -->
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="584dp" />
```

If you can't see the color you want, please add it to the `colors.xml` file stored in the `values` folder.
This is an example of a `colors.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="black">#333333</color>
</resources>
```

You should already have this file, if not, add it.

Comment: this won't change buttons color, it will replace whole background for solid rectangle and remove e.g. shadow under it or rounded corners. VERY bad solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use Material Button and it's won't affect ripple and elevation of Button

[image]

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint=""ff0000"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution which has helped me before. Have a look in your themes.xml file .
Change to  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).